# WooCommerce Membership - Search by custom meta key not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement searching on custom meta key of WooCommerce Membership. Phone number here is shown by getting post type wc_user_membership's custom meta key '_billing_phone'. Any idea why it is not working?

[image: Screenshot of WC Members list]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_wc_user_membership_search_fields', 'billing_phone_searchable_field' );
function billing_phone_searchable_field( $meta_keys ){
    $meta_keys[] = '_billing_phone';
    return $meta_keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referring to https://www.fruitdudragon.com/woocommerce-membership-plugin-include-custom-field-in-admin-search/

```
function advanced_admin_custom_search($pieces, WP_Query $wp_query) {
global $wpdb;

if (!is_admin() ) return $pieces;

if (!array_key_exists('post_type', $wp_query->query)) return $pieces;

// bail out if not the correct post type
if ( 'wc_user_membership' === $wp_query->query['post_type'] ) {
   
    // $wp_query->set( 'post_type',  'wc_user_membership' );

    // search
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['s'] ) ) {
        
        // add here your acf fields
        $list_searcheable_acf = array("my_acf_field_name");

        // get search expression
        $terms = $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ];
                
        // explode search expression to get search terms
        $exploded = explode( ' ', $terms );
        if( $exploded === FALSE || count( $exploded ) == 0 )
            $exploded = array( 0 => $terms );
            
        // reset search in order to rebuilt it as we whish
        $where = $pieces['where'];
        
        foreach( $exploded as $tag ) :
            $where .= " 
           OR EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->postmeta . "
                    WHERE post_id = " . $wpdb->posts . ".ID
                        AND " . $wpdb->posts . ".post_type = 'wc_user_membership'
                        AND (";
            foreach ($list_searcheable_acf as $searcheable_acf) :
                $where .= " (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$tag}[[:>:]]') ";
            endforeach;
                $where .= ")
            )";
        endforeach;

        // replace the where clauses
        $pieces['where'] = $where;
    }
}

return $pieces;
}


add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'advanced_admin_custom_search', 500, 2 );
```